# How to work out bubble size and rising velocity in turbulent flow?

Tags: electrochemistry

Is there a way to determine bubble size and rising velocity in turbulent flow? I know stokes law but this is only valid for laminar flow.

Comment: I'd say fluid dynamics pretty squarely fits into physics, not chemistry, so this question may have to be moved.

Comment: It is a chemical engineering question.

Comment: @Katherine CFD would be a general place to start. You may want to elaborate on what type of answer you're looking for - experimental, theoretical, etc.